# Не могу получить текст из чужого RICHEDIT50W через SendMessage

Tags: delphi, winapi, sendmessage

Имеется программка Fiddler с элементом RICHEDIT50W, из которого собственно нужно получить текст.

```
TxtLen := SendMessage(wnd2, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
```

Показывает 7161 символ, что верно. Приведу переменные:

```
TxtLen: integer;
TexQwTxt: array of Char;
TxtStr: String;
```

Далее увеличиваем массив для записи:

```
SetLength(TexQwTxt, TxtLen+1);
```

А дальше, собственно, должно происходить считывание текста:

```
SendMessage(wnd2, WM_GETTEXT, TxtLen+1, Integer(@TexQwTxt));

TxtStr:='';
for I := 0 to TxtLen-1 do
   TxtStr:=TxtStr+TexQwTxt[i];
Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(TxtStr);
```

И memo пустой!

Подскажите, где накосячил и как поправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Динамический массив уже указатель, поэтому сам должен использоваться в качестве ссылки на его данные, без лишнего взятия адреса

```
SendMessage(wnd2, WM_GETTEXT, TxtLen+1, Integer(TexQwTxt));
//и тут попроще:
SetString(TxtStr, PChar(TexQwTxt), TxtLen);
```

собственно, массив и не нужен

```
 SetLength(TxtStr, TxtLen);
 SendMessage(wnd2, WM_GETTEXT, TxtLen, Integer(TxtStr));
 Memo1.Lines.Add(TxtStr);
```

Comment: E2089 Invalid typecast

Comment: В SendMessage(wnd2, WM_GETTEXT, TxtLen, Integer(TxtStr));

Comment: А с SendMessage(wnd2, WM_GETTEXT, TxtLen+1, Integer(TexQwTxt));

Comment: Пустой memo....

Comment: Изменил  Integer(TxtStr)) на lParam(TxtStr))

Comment: Заработало!!!!!

Comment: Спасибо, второй метод с небольшой правкой заработал